# How can I fetch ​exploration decay rate of an iterable Q-table in Python?

Tags: q-learning

I have done creating the virtual environment, creating the Q-table, initializing the q-parameters, then I made a training module and stored it in a `numpy` array. After completion of training, I have updated the q-table and now I get the plots for the explorations But how can I code for rate decay? Here is my sample code for every step of the training module,

```
for step in range(max_steps): 
        exploration_rate_threshold = random.uniform(0,1)

        if exploration_rate_threshold > exploration_rate:
            action = np.argmax(q_table[state,:])
        else:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to calculate the exploration rate decay:

```
exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate + \ (max_exploration_rate - min_exploration_rate) * np.exp(-exploration_decay_rate*episode)
```

Comment: why is exploration_decay_rate negative in np.exp()?

Comment: on finish of every step of training, exploration rate decreases or decays at a rate proportional to its ongoing decay value. Hence, its negative for every episode.